# Binary arithmetic: why hash%n is equivalent to hash&(n-1)?

Tags: java, hashmap, bucket

I have been studying Java HashMap source code, the part of it which decides in what bucket to put an object and saw this change in Java 7 (8) as compared to Java 6.
Additionally I conducted numerous experiments and both expressions yeild the same result:

```
hash % n
and
hash & (n - 1)
where n - the array length that must be power of 2.
```

I just cannot figure out why is it true? Is there any theorem or some math laws that prove these statement are equal? Basically I want to understand the inference and prove the equivalence of those two statements.

*PS. If n is not a power of 2 number, the equivalence breaks immedeately.*

Comment: Think about the bits in `(n - 1)` if `n` is a power of 2 (or `((1 << i) - 1)`, if you want to simplify the constraint on `n`)

Comment: Hint: one less than a power of 2 written in bicimal consists of solely 1 bits. Not much point in saying much more since the "duplicate police" on the Java tag pretty much close everything off.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Only when there's a duplicate. If you think this is a duplicate of another question, I suggest you show which one. Plenty of Java questions *aren't* closed as duplicates.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Although I haven't indulged myself in performing any real analysis on this, I observe that the dupe closures on the Java tag are considerably more lateral than ones in C and C++, to the point where I've pretty much given up contributing on the Java tag. So I see "Only when there's a duplicate" as the intention, but often not followed in many instances.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Whereas I see the opposite - I see lots of duplicate questions being asked and correctly closed as duplicates, but few non-duplicate questions being closed. I certainly don't think it's useful to complain about the "duplicate police" when there's no sign that *anyone* has voted to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Very well, let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 4):

If n is a power of two that mean its binary representation is `10000....`,
n-1 for that matter is `1111111...` with one less digit.

That means that binary &-ing with `(n-1)` preserves just exactly the number of bits in `k` that `n-1` has set.

Example `n = 8: 1000, n-1 = 7: 111`
&-ing for example `k = 201: 11001001`
`k % n = k & (n-1) = 11001001 & 111 = 001 = 1`.

%-ing with a power of 2 means that in binary you just strip everything away that is above (including) the only set bit: for n = 8 that means stripping everything over (including) the 4th bit. And that is exactly what the &-ing does at well.

---

A side effect is that using `&` is commutative: `hash & (n - 1)` is equivalent to `(n - 1) & hash` which is not true for `%`, the jdk source code in many places uses the later, e.g. [in `getNode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f#569)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this statement "%-ing with a power of 2 means that in binary you just strip everything away that is above (including) the only set bit..", it is not so obvious, you see. I feel like this is the key to understand the entire conversion...

Comment: @AndreasGelever sure, I will do elaborate today evening. In the meantime compare it to mod base 10. for example 34567 % 1000 -> Strip everything above including 1000 -> 567

Comment: Well, I can see that the trick works for numbers like 10, 100, 1000 etc. Which probably can be generalized like ...all numbers multiple of the base of numeral system (but I am not sure about this statement). But it is still intuitive and not apparent for binary system at all... so the question remains open.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the bits in `(n - 1)` if `n` is a power of 2 (or `((1 << i) - 1)`, if you want to simplify the constraint on `n`):

If `n` is, say, 16 (`= 1 << 4)`, then `n - 1` is 15, and the bit representation of `15` and `16` (as 32-bit `int`s) are:

```
 1 = 00000000000000000000000000000001  // Shift by 4 to get...
16 = 00000000000000000000000000010000  // Subtract 1 to get...
15 = 00000000000000000000000000001111
```

So just the lowest 4 bits are set in 15. If you `&` this with another int, it will only allow bits in the last 4 bits of that number to be set in the result, so the value will only be in the range 0-15, so it's like doing `% 16`.

---

However, note that this equivalence doesn't hold for a negative first operand:

```
    System.out.println(-1 % 2);    // -1
    System.out.println(-1 & (2-1));  //  1
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nQP2bW)

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic rule for integer `/` and `%` is:

```
x*(y/x) + (y%x) = y
```

What about a negative `hash` -4 and a positive `n` 8?

```
8*0 + (-4%8) = -4
```

Hence modulo maintains the sign.

```
-4 % 8 = -4
-4 & 7 = 4
```

Or:

```
int t = hash%n;
if (t < 0) {
   t += n;
}
assert t == (hash & (n-1));
```

So in the earlier java with `%n` `hash` had to be positive to begin with.
Now hash may be negative, more solid and better hashing.
**So that was a sound reason for this subtle change in java source code.**

---

***Background:***

2<sup>n</sup> is a **1** followed by n-1 **0**s (in binary).
2<sup>n</sup> - 1 is n-1 **1**s.

Hence for n being a positive power of 2, and some positive number h:

```
h % n == h & (n-1)
```

Another usage is to count bits in an int. The class Integer has just such a function.

```
int bits = 0;
while (x != 0) {
    x &= x - 1;
    ++bits;
}
```